# Recommendations on methods to predict sales data

Tags: predictive-models, forecasting, arima, arma

I'm very inexperienced in statistical analysis. I think my question is fairly basic so I hope I can get some good pointers so I will be able to learn more efficiently.

I have extensive hourly sales data of a website going back years and I would like to make predictions on what the most important metrics (most likely sessions and order total) should be in the next few hours. The available data covers almost everything about transactions, how much money were spent, how many sessions, how many visits, etc, with an hourly granularity. Obviously these data follow yearly patterns, seasonal patterns, and daily patterns. i.e. growth is trending up year to year, holiday seasons are more busy, and it's more quiet during the night and busy during the day.

What are some established statistical model that can be used for the hourly prediction? The predictions only need to be made for the next few hours, but should be fairly accurate; they should be almost always correct within some margins unless major abnormalities happen.

I have looked into ARMA/ARIMA methods but I'm unclear if what I want to do is the best fit, since I have more information about my time series. For example, there is clearly a 24 hour cycle in the data. Please let me know what things I should be looking into. Thank you very much!

Comment: ARMA is a model for stationary time series data. Use ARIMA if your data seems to be non-stationary. You can either plot or run a Dickey-Fuller test to find if your data is stationary or not. But check out for seasonality too. You may need to model your data with a SARIMA (Seasonal ARIMA) model if you find seasonality in your data. Basically only you can test your data for these issues. No one can help you theoretically without seeing the data. But I suspect seasonality in these kinds of sales data. Check out for that.

Comment: @BlainWaan, thanks! I will study up on SARIMA then. Are there other potential candidates that you might suggest?

Comment: This is an application based easy and good book: http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2765719-time-series-analysis